# Does John 12:41 prove the doctrine of the trinity?

Tags: john, isaiah, messiah, john-the-baptist

Does John 12:41 prove the doctrine of the trinity, in John 12:41 it says:

> These things said Esaias, when he saw his glory, and spake of him.

This is quoting from Isaiah 6:1-5:

> In the year that king Uzziah died I saw also the Lord sitting upon a
> throne, high and lifted up, and his train filled the temple.
>
> Above it stood the seraphims: each one had six wings; with twain he
> covered his face, and with twain he covered his feet, and with twain
> he did fly.
>
> And one cried unto another, and said, Holy, holy, holy, is the Lord of
> hosts: the whole earth is full of his glory.
>
> And the posts of the door moved at the voice of him that cried, and
> the house was filled with smoke.
>
> Then said I, Woe is me! for I am undone; because I am a man of unclean
> lips, and I dwell in the midst of a people of unclean lips: for mine
> eyes have seen the King, the Lord of hosts.

Did Isaiah see the glory of God or of Jesus and could this be given evidence for the holy trinity?

Comment: To be clear, proving the deity of Jesus does *not* prove the Trinity. You also have to prove both the personhood *and* the deity of the **Holy Spirit**. Even if this proves that Jesus is God, you still have not proved that the Holy Spirit is God, hence in either scenario(whether or not this proves the deity of Christ), the Trinity doctrine is left unproven. Although, it would still be a great something if you could prove that Jesus is God.

Comment: Does X prove the Trinity is never a good question format. What are answers going to do other than say yes or no? If a single verse could solve the doctrine of God then there wouldn't be any debate about it. Instead it's better to ask "How is verse X accounted for by position Y?" on the [christianity.se] site.

Comment: As it stands, this is not a valid question - one of two things should happen - either (1) it should be migrated to Christianity SX, or, (2) reworded to say something like, "Does Jojm 12:41 support the idea of Jesus' divinity?", or better, "To what passage in Isaiah does  John 12:41 refer?"  As it sits, it not at all obvious that John 12:41 refers to Isa 6.

Comment: The revelation of God (in the true nature of God) is the coming of the Son : _This is my beloved Son in whom I am well pleased_ - for the Father sends the Son and the Son reveals the Father. Without further revelation the former knowledge of God (in ancient times) was - as yet - incomplete.

Comment: Yo appear to be trying to 'prove' something (the previous question and this one) but you are not stating (exactly) what you are trying to 'prove'. On this site you can only ask a question about the wording that is on the page of scripture. You cannot add what is termed 'theology' (that is to say an exterior construct - whether right or wrong) to the page. Ask what is visible in the words and you will fare better, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not prove the Trinity. However, John 12:41 does prove the deity of Jesus Christ. One need only follow the pronouns and the verbs. Isaiah saw the glory of YHWH. There is only ONE time that Isaiah saw the gory of YHWH which is at Isaiah 6:1-5.

John says that Isaiah saw "literally" his glory, the glory of Jesus. The verb Isaiah used for "saw" in 6:1 is (ra'ah). In the qal, it refers to the act of seeing in the literal sense, to see with the eyes (as opposed to, for example "machazeh", which is the act or event of an ecstatic "vision").

In referring to this event, John uses the Greek word ("eidon"), also a verb referring to the act of seeing with the eyes in the natural sense. We know that God the Father is invisible, "whom no man hath seen, nor can see" (1 Timothy 6:16). He is transcendent and lives in unapproachable light (1 Timothy 6:16).

But the Son is the "image of the invisible God" (Colossians 1:15). Moreover the Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father. What is known of the Father is revealed through the Son. To see the Son is to see the essence of the Father. (John 1:18, 10:30; 12:45, 14:9, Hebrews 1:3). Jesus makes this clear at John 12:45, "And he who beholds Me beholds the One who sent Me."

There is only ONE time when Isaiah saw someone he, speaking by the Holy Spirit identified as "YHWH" and John's spirit-inspired narrative of the interactions of Jesus with the Jews in the 11th and 12th chapter of his gospel, including their rejection of Christ, says that what Isaiah saw was HIS (i.e Jesus') glory.

This works in perfect harmony with John's whole purpose, given the FACT that John had previously identified the one who became flesh and dwelt among us (John 1:14) as "God." (John 1:1).

Answer (score -1):

What IS the glory of God?

As God is spirit and invisible, any glory that one (like Moses) might see is an effect of God's presence, a manifestation of God's presence in a way that we might grasp and witness that is truly glorious and bewildering. It could be a great light, a cloud, a pillar of fire - these effects are not God - they are the result of His being in our proximity. God is spirit and invisible!

> In the year of King Uzziah’s death I saw the Lord sitting on a throne...

No he didn't. He saw a *vision* of God's glory *represented* by the things he saw. God is spirit and invisible!

We also understand that Jesus is not the manifestation of the Father, but of the logos - God's word. He IS NOT the Father become flesh, but the logos become flesh. To twist the scriptures to fit some pre-configured doctrine is to invite all manner of confusion and further error.

We also should understand that the logos is not God as God is God. 1John 1:1 shows it to be a which and a what - this is not speaking of God, a living entity, but the word, plan, purpose, will of God as the logos.

> That which was from the beginning, which we have heard, which we have seen with our eyes, which we have looked at and our hands have touched—this we proclaim concerning the Word of life. 1John 1:1

Jesus is the same manifestation of the logos John describes in John 1. A basic and humble reading of John 1 indicates that Jesus is not the logos in v1-3, because he is the fleshly *result* of v14 when he was born of Mary ~2000 yrs ago. Whatever other understandings of this passage exist are without credibility or basic logic and cause massive contradictions with the scripture in other places.

Jesus being the *image* of God, makes him no more God that the glory OF God makes the glory God. They are both *representations* OF God - because there is only one God as we are told repeatedly since the beginning.

So no, Isaiah did not see the glory of Jesus - Jesus was - according to all the scriptures - not born yet! Certainly he was promised and prophesied to come - "in these last days". Heb 1

If we choose to insert Jesus wherever we want, in history or verse, based on the whim of men's imaginations, we don't need the bible at all.

Jesus declared quite simply,

> As it is, you are looking for a way to kill me, a man who has told you the truth that I heard from God. John 8:40

- a man - a man is not God!
- he speaks the truth - not 1/2 truth, not lies, not deception.
- he heard this from God. So we still want to make Jesus God too even though it makes no sense?
- he is going to be killed - does God die, does Jesus have two natures that he might die in one and not the other??? How bizarre that we can not simply read what is written but extend the fanciful deceptions of men who replaced the Apostle's teachings - which they *heard* from Christ and the holy spirit.

**Does John 12:41 prove the doctrine of the trinity?**

No, neither does it prove Jesus' deity. Unless we read in that which we want to read and pretend that the words God has delivered are of little significance and must be rewritten, added to (1John 5:7 and many others) and reconfigured to fit men's dogma.

**Did Isaiah see the glory of God?**

Yes - that is what we are told.

**or of Jesus?**

NO, that would be silly.

**and could this be given evidence for the holy trinity?**

No, there is no biblical evidence for the trinity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132804/discussion-between-rajesh-and-steveowen).

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, that is what he said but he also said Isaiah saw the glory of God but it was not Jesus Christ, "that would be silly." Isaiah didn't think it was "silly" and neither did the Apostle John. And if you noticed he whole thing is with the Trinity and neither the Isaiah or the John text is about the Trinity which means he is changing the subject. He not only denies the Trinity but he denies the deity of Jesus Christ which is the only think I'm concerned with and want him to see. "Who do people say who the Son of Man is" Matthew 16:13. Do you believe Isaiah saw Jesus Christ on the throne?

Comment: @curious We are invited to give a *reason* for the DV - you seem to like to delete such comments.

Comment: @steveowen One comment saying "this part of your post is very poorly reasoned/misunderstands the Greek/ignores the key part of neighbouring verse" is fine, that's a good use of comments, and I rarely delete comments like that. Comments that just assert different theology, or extended comment debates, are not good uses of comments, and those I do delete.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Yes, I agree with your interpretation, Mr. Bond. That's why I liked your answer. I'm just saying that maybe steveowen has some great points too. I can think two different answers have great points; I just think your answer has much better points than steveowen's. Have a great day! :)